# Linked Excel file opens when Access front end opens- How to stop this behavior

Tags: excel, database, vba, ms-access

I have Ms access- frond end which is distributed to more than 50 Users and its works very well until today i come across a weird behavior.

today, I have linked one excel file in back end and use this linked table in front end a create a form using query (view only) and updated my front end. through my test I found that if I open two instance of my front end and open the newly created form than in second instance access open my the linked Excel file as readonly.

My question is, how can i avoid this behavior? I don't want my users to see this excel file by any way. is there any work around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's by design. An Excel workbook hosted on premise cannot be shared for writing.

One workaround is to create a copy of the workbook for each user. For instance, let your application copy the workbook from the shared location to a local subfolder of *%LocalAppData%*, the user's local data folder, and link to that.

Comment: Or you could consume the file and create a local access table (assuming the file isnt too large). I dont see why the excel file as a linked table should be necessary but I dont understand its use or its importance.