# Refresh linked Excel file path in Ms access at run time

Tags: excel, database, vba, ms-access

After getting a suggestion from this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56426985/linked-excel-file-opens-when-access-front-end-opens-how-to-stop-this-behavior)

I am trying to refreshlink with a new path of an Excel file in Ms access at run time.

I tried a following

```
Dim td As DAO.TableDef
Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb()
Set td = db.TableDefs('Ersatz')   
td.Connect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\LocalErsatzliste\SAP.xlsx;Extended Properties = Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=2;ACCDB=YES"
td.RefreshLink
```

at line `td.RefreshLink` I am getting **runtime error 3170 Could not find installable ISAM**.

I have tried different string like

```
td.connect = "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\LocalErsatzliste\SAP.xlsx"
```

also this

```
td.connect = "Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=2;ACCDB=YES;DATABASE= C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\LocalErsatzliste\SAP.xlsx"
```

by using above line I am getting **runtime error 3044**

PS: I have multiple table but I want only this table to change its path at run time.

**Solution :**

there was spacing problem in the string the new and final string which works is

```
Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=2;ACCDB=YES;DATABASE=C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Ersatzliste\SAP.xlsx
```

Comment: Start by inspecting the connection string of a linked table by using `Debug.Print td.Connect`. These strings are all far from valid.

Comment: @ErikA I have tried the same it give me `Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=2;ACCDB=YES;DATABASE=\\ Access\Backend\Ersatzteilliste\SAP Ersatzteilliste.xlsx` and the same i have used just replacing the path of file and it gives me runtime error 3044

Comment: @ErikA I have tried once again i got an **error 3436 Failure Creating file**

Comment: Try `"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\LocalErsatzliste\SAP.xlsx;Extended Properties = ""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=2;ACCDB=YES"""`